# Crear objeto con Key anidadas apartir de un array

Tags: javascript, array, object

a partir de este array

```
["RNZ-001", "RNZ-001.2", "RNZ-001.2.1"]
```

Necesito crear un objeto con esta estructura?

```
{"RNZ-001":
          [
          {"RNZ-001.2":[
                       {"RNZ-001.2.1":[]}
                       ]
          }]
}
```

Existe alguna función para poder hacer relativamente facilmente?
Les agradezco la respuesta.

Saludos.

Comment: Esta pregunta fue marcada negativamente y no entiendo porque. Busque muchisimo en internet y no pude encontrar nada que me explique esto. Si alguno puede darme una idea la agradeceria.

Comment: No existe una función que haga exactamente lo que necesitas. Para conseguirlo debes crearla tu mismo. Has intentado algo? Tienes alguna idea de cómo resolverlo? No solo es preguntar, la idea es que demuestres que al menos lo has intentado. Si tienes al menos una idea básica, edita la pregunta y pon lo que has intentado. Seguro con eso la puntuación sube.

Comment: Gracias, mauricio. Si trate varias cosas logro anidar un nivel pero el resto de los valores me quedan todos en ese segundo nivel. Esta tarde subo que es lo que ya hice.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te puede servir esto:

```
const arr = ["RNZ-001", "RNZ-001.2", "RNZ-001.2.1"];

let obj = {};
let temp = [];

for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  obj = temp = [{ [arr[i]]: temp }];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
```

Lo que hace es es guardar en una variable temporal `temp` lo que tiene esa misma variable en cada iteración. En la primera iteración `temp` es un arreglo vacio, pero se guarda el tercer item en un arreglo con forma de objecto con el valor de `temp`.  Y así sucesivamente. Cabe aclarar que va iterando al revés, desde el último item en el array hacia el primero.

Y el resultado sería el siguiente:

```
[
    {
        "RNZ-001": [
            {
                "RNZ-001.2": [
                    {
                        "RNZ-001.2.1": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: El resultado obtenido no es exactamente el esperado, visualmente se parece, pero es sintácticamente diferente al que se pide. Se pide un Objeto, el procedimiento devuelve un Array.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago usando recursión, imagino que existen otras formas, pero mi método devuelve el objeto con los `keys` anidados como los necesitas:

```js
const arr = ["RNZ-001", "RNZ-001.2", "RNZ-001.2.1"];

//creamos un objeto temporal vacío:
let objTemporal = {};

//inicializamos la recursión en cero, el límite vendrá
//dado por el tamaño de nuestro Array.
 let inicio = 0;
 
 // declaramos la función recursiva
 
 function anidar(obj,ini) {
   //verificamos que nuestro límite se cumple
   if (ini === arr.length -1) {// recordar que los indices de nuestro array llegan hasta arr.length - 1
     return {[arr[ini]]: [obj]}; // devuelvo un objeto
   }
   return {[arr[ini]]: [anidar(obj,ini + 1)]}; // la llamada recursiva, incrementando el valor de inicio
 }
 
 // por último declaramos una variable que contendrá
 // nuestro objeto con las claves anidadas
 // en el orden que se dan en el array.
 
 const objeto = anidar(objTemporal,inicio);
 
 // verificamos por consola
 
 console.log(objeto);
 
 // la última clave anidada del objeto contiene un array con un objeto vacío, es el costo de la recursión, espero eso no sea un problema.
```

La función `anidar()` en este caso devuelve lo siguiente:

```js
{
  "RNZ-001": [
    {
      "RNZ-001.2": [
        {
          "RNZ-001.2.1": [
            {}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Espero que este sea el resultado que esperas. Salvando el hecho de que la clave anidada más profunda contiene un array con un objeto vacío.